# Set mdDialog to not resize to fit content after opening

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material, mddialog

I have a material design $mdDialog with a search bar. When the results of the search are smaller (fewer characters) the dialog shrinks to fit the width. Is there a way to set the width to stay fixed on init?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding)

Assuming your dialog is a component in itself.

You can add a property in the component as something like this

```
@HostBinding('class.fix-width')
public fixWidth: boolean = false;
```

Set this property to true in `init`.

in css add your fixed width using the above class, somehting like this

```
:host {

    &.fix-width {
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

This will fix the width, when your dialog is rendered. 
You can remove the class by setting the property back to false whenever required.

Comment: Is there a way to have the width be dynamic based on screen size and content on init() but then remain at that exact width if the content changes? I don't want to have to set an arbitrary px width in css

Comment: you can use calc() function for dynamic width. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc if this works